# change package name on build android app

Tags: android, maven

I'm having some questions about how to make different builds (flavors) in android, I need to make two apks, with different package-name. Inside the code just I need to change an URL and enable some tracking libs to make a DEVEL and PROD releases . How can I do this? I don't want to use Gradle for now, until they make an stable release. Any idea using maven or any trick?